# change the load() text based on variable?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

In the following script, all I need to do is change the integer before the `.php` in each of the `.load()` functions.

That is, as `bio_id` is either incremented or decremented, the filename `1.php` will increment or decrement with `bio_id`. I'm not sure how to do that.

```
<script>
    $("#bio").load("assets/includes/bios/1.php");
</script>
<div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button id="prev" type="button" class="btn btn-default disabled" onclick="prevBio()">Previous</button>
    <button id="next" type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="nextBio()">Next</button>
</div>

<script>
    /* bio id number */
    var bio_id = 1;
    var new_bio = 1;

    function nextBio() {
        bio_id++;
        new_bio = bio_id;
        console.log(bio_id);
        $('#bio').load("assets/includes/bios/2.php"); 

        if (new_bio > 1 && bio_id < 12) {
            $('#prev').removeClass('disabled');
            $('#next').removeClass('disabled');
        } 
        else if (new_bio == 12) {
            $('#next').addClass('disabled');
        }
        return bio_id;
    }

    function prevBio() {
        bio_id--;
        new_bio = bio_id;
        console.log(bio_id);
        $('#bio').load("assets/includes/bios/2.php"); 

        if(new_bio == 1) {
            $('#prev').addClass('disabled');
        }
        else if (new_bio > 1 && bio_id < 12) {
            $('#prev').removeClass('disabled');
            $('#next').removeClass('disabled');
        } 
        else if (new_bio == 12) {
            $('#next').addClass('disabled');
        }

        return bio_id;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Your question looks unclear. Do you want to [edit] it again?

Answer (score 1):

What's great about javascript is that the typing is so loose, so you can just do something like this to concatenate your strings:

```js
bio_id=12;
alert('hello' + bio_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in your case it would be:

`$('#bio').load("assets/includes/bios/" + bio_id + ".php");`

Comment: I'll try it. Thanks! I'm still trying to learn Javascript and jQuery... so this is fairly new to me.